# C#: Force a pointer to never be null

Tags: c#, .net, properties, null, nullable

I have a class with a property: `public MyClass myProperty { get; set; }`. When a object is created, this property is null.

I wanted it to automatically call a `MyClass()` and instantiate this property, and compiler throw error for a `myObject.myProperty = null;`.

Is it possible to do that in C#? Or do I need to encapsulate a verification in the property's getter?

Comment: Why don't you just provide it a default value inline or in the constructor? You can't enforce non-nullness -- at most you can do a runtime check. There is a proposal for this for C# 7 but let's hope that won't go through.

Comment: You can't get the compiler to do this, because you could do `myObject.myProperty = someMethodDefinedInAnotherAssembly();` which the compiler can't  check. Only a runtime check can be done.

Comment: How about using a struct if your `MyClass` is a just a value?

Comment: I provide a default object in constructor, but the property can still be set null later. Ok I get that compiler can't check for possible null from other assembly/dll, so sad.